# Add Cordova Plugin to existing iOS project with Cordova WebView

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordovawebview

I have an iOS project in which i added Cordova WebView. It works fine, but now i need to add some more plugins i.e. logging and others. I tried using following command.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
```

But this gives me following error.

```
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
```

What should be the right directory to execute this command? I tried the path which config.xml and the CordovaLib?

Comment: How did you add the Cordova WebView? The `cordova` command (from the cordova CLI) will only work on a project you created with `cordova create myProject`. 

Maybe you could try installing the plugins by hand with the `plugman` tool.

Comment: I added the plugins using plugman. I included the cordova.js file too in my html file. But they are not loading.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Plugins are added correctly in the Plugins folder, config.xml gets updated too. But when i try to log something through console.log() nothing happens.